# How to get the HTML element in an new windows triggered by javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, webforms, browser

i'm using WebBrowser control in Windows Forms App to automate a website and do some actions, so i need to know the HTML elements in the website(for example, textbox id, button id).

Everything is running smooth until i meet one situation. There are a html link element which point back to itself (eg: "http://www.aaa.com") but trigger a new windows with different url (eg: "http://www.bbb.com"). Below is the html link element :

```
< a href="#" class="toolbar" id="Export_Link" onclick="showExportWindow();" title="Export me">Exports &amp; Reports< /a>
```

It showed up a new window with different url and therefore, the WebBrowser control unable to get the HTML element in the new window because it trace back the html element in the old window ("http://www.aaa.com#") and not the new window ("http://www.bbb.com")

Please help me! I'm stucking here for 1 weeks already! Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: For me, problem is unclear. I don't understand.

Comment: which part u don't understand? :)

Comment: this: It showed up a new window with different url and therefore, the WebBrowser control unable to get the HTML element in the new window because it trace back the html element in the old window ("http://www.aaa.com#") and not the new window ("http://www.bbb.com")

Comment: aaa.com and bbb.com is an example of diffrent links. aaa.com is the current window url, and bbb.com is the url link of the new windows after clicking on the html link element. As u can see from above, the html link element is pointing to href = "#" , it means it will point back to the same url which is from aaa.com to aaa.com#. However, after i click on the html link element, it start up a new windows with bbb.com url, although the html link element is pointing to itself. so i think it is because of javascript function showExportWindow() trigger it...and i face the problem because of this..

Comment: Of course that is because of javascript code in the onclick handler. This function probably opens the bbb.com when you click the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understand your problem correctly, but it seems that you are struggling with the "#" link. It's a common practice to link to the external page, even if you want to use javascript to open this page. This provides a good fallback for browsers with disabled javascript support.

```
<a href="otherpage.html" onclick="window.open('otherpage.html','external'); return false;">Other</a>
```

Pay regard to the **return false;** at the end of the javascript, it's necessary to tell the browser that the "normal" page link shouldn't be followed when the javascript runs.

Comment: One reason I tend to NOT use links but text click handlers sometimes.